# two functions on click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I have these two functions that i want to apply to the same click (i did have them both inside the click function with the same result... that the image toggle works every time but the show/hide toggle ("optionToggle") only works first time. Both work fine seperately

thanks in advance

```
function imageToggle() {
    var img = $('.choices').find('.btn').children().children('img');
    img.toggle(function () {img.attr("src","images/misc/dotr-add.png");},
    function () {img.attr("src","images/misc/dotr-minus.png");}
    );
}


function optionToggle() {
    var option = $('.choices').find('.btn').closest('.dishActions').children('.option');
    option.toggle();
}
$('.btn').click(function() {
    optionToggle(); 
    imageToggle();
});
```

here is the code -

```
<div class="dishActions"> 
    <!-- DISH CHOICE --> 
    <div class="choices"> 
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/misc/dotr-add.png" height="40" width="40" alt="button up" border="0" /> 
        </div> 
        <div class="choicesTxt">Choices </div> 
    </div> 
    <!-- DISH OPTIONS --> 
    <div class="option">
```

Comment: How about a JSFiddle with this?

Comment: A fiddle, demo, or at the very least the HTML you are using would be very helpful here.

Comment: The toggle() function used that way has been removed in newer versions of jQuery, now it only hides and shows elements, and using that version of it inside another event handler is really a no go !

Comment: ah! any suggestions as to swapping out an image?
without changing the class name(background image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var state = $(this).data('state'),
        image = state ? 'dotr-add' : 'dotr-minus';
    $(this).data('state', !state)
           .find('img')
           .prop('src', 'images/misc/' + image + '.png');
});
```

**EDIT:**

I don't see why you'd want this, but with functions :

```
function imageToggle(state, elem) {
    var image = state ? 'dotr-add' : 'dotr-minus';

    $(elem).find('img').prop('src', 'images/misc/' + image + '.png');
}

function optionToggle(state, elem) {
    $(elem).closest('.dishActions').children('.option').toggle(!state);
}

$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var state = $(this).data('state');
    imageToggle(state, this);
    optionToggle(state, this);
    $(this).data('state', !state)
});
```

Comment: awesome! works a treat, thanks very much. now to try and work out what youve done! ;)

Comment: It stores true or false in data() on each element, like an on/off switch to keep track of the current state, and do the opposite the next time it's clicked !

Comment: if wanted this as an stand alone function though....im trying to create is as i said originally, so what would i substitute for (this).

function openOption () {....

Comment: $(this) can be replaced with img in your method